# Can I have multi-column Radio groups in both Delphi and HTML?

Tags: html, css, delphi

Can I have multi-column Radio groups in both Delphi and HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML, you can define your own layout by simply placing the radio buttons you like in a table like e.g.:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk">Milk<br />
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter">Butter<br />
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese">Cheese
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Water">Water<br />
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Bread">Bread<br />
            <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Soda">Soda
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For the Delphi part, I don't know, since I'm not familar with Delphi.

If it is similar to Windows Forms, I think you simply use the visual designer to place the single radio buttons in whatever position you like them to have.

Comment: Probably with floating `div` tags, this is something ouf of my scope. I still do use tables for these kind of things.

Answer (score 6):

In Delphi, RadioGroup has Columns property which you can set.

Below code will set 3 columns

```
RadioGroup1.Columns := 3;
```